# IAP not prepared. Check if Google Play service is available

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

I am buildin app on flutter and using latest (5.0.1)
flutter_inapp_purchase plugin. https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_inapp_purchase

I notced that i randomly get this error: `"IAP not prepared. Check if Google Play service is available"` wehn caling await `FlutterInappPurchase.instance.initConnection;` on emulators AND real devices (mostly on Android) PROD and DEV builds. If i get this error i re-open an app and error is gone. What can cause this behaviour? How can i solve it? Maybe i should retry intialization until succeeded.

p.s. I am intializing connection very early - on app startup. Maybe i have to postpone intialization?

All thoughts and help are welcome

Answer (score 0):

So, this packages seems to be dead. There ia an alternatvibe - flutte rnative package but it is also not usable because of these bugs:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85529
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85448

and flutter team does not treat them as important.

So finally i switched to revenue cat which has briiant flutter plugin and integration took few hours. A bit regret of my wasted time on those two integrations....